# How do I load a module relative to script in Raku with Raku equivalent of FindBin

Tags: module, raku

Suppose I have 2 files in a directory

```
p.pl  
Mod.pm
```

In perl5 I can load a module Mod.pm from p.pl via:

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin";
...
use Mod;
```

I wonder what the `Raku` equivalent would be (if files are p.raku and Mod.rakumod)?

What I want to accomplish is to load a module relative to a script.

- I want to execute without setting an env variable prior to starting a script.
- I dont want to install the modules with zef.
- I dont want to be
  forced to set the cwd to the scripts directory, meaning if p.raku and Mod.rakumod are in directory d1 that is in turn in directory d0 I want to be able to run `cd d0; rakudo d1/p.raku` as well as `cd d1; rakudo p.raku`

Comment: If none of the SOs in [a search of SO for "\[raku\] relative module"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braku%5D+relative+module) help, please add details to your question explaining why not. Thx.

Comment: @raiph rephrased it

Comment: $*PROGRAM and use lib?

Comment: @ValleLukas : I tried ```use lib IO::PATH.new($*PROGRAM).dirname;``` but  there is an error: "Could not evaluate arguments...."

Comment: use lib $*PROGRAM.dirname;

Comment: @ValleLukas : thanks that worked. Will add this as an answer.

Comment: @KonradEisele Is the answer you've written acceptable? If so, please consider accepting it. If not, please consider commenting on how other answers might improve on it. By accepting one you find acceptable you signal to the rest of us that you're sufficiently satisfied with the accepted answer to close down further effort to write answers. You can (and imo should) always switch your acceptance to a different answer if you later decide it feels better to you. There's nothing to stop folk, and lots to commend, moving acceptance between answers as folk learn more over the years and revisit SOs.

Comment: @raiph : yes I want to accept it. But I cannot do it before 2 days because I answered it myself. If someone else wants to answer I can delete mine and then accept directly.

Comment: @KonradEisele Thx for following up. All should now be clear to all. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As ValleLukas explained:

```
use lib $*PROGRAM.dirname
use Mod;
```

can be used.